# Git: compare diffs of two commits

Tags: git

I have 2 commits and suspect them introduce same difference. I want compare diffs introduced by these commits (not commits itself).

I can do this with next commands

```
$ git show ad7cfab50e63784bb3168a61101c4f17726b98f1 > d1
$ git show 4ec2d3d981948542111a04172c1d21a5524991f2 > d2
$ diff d1 d2
```

But may be more convenient way exists?

Comment: Why don't you just wrap those three commands in a bash function that you can use as follows: `compare_commits` *`commit1 commit2`*  ?

Comment: If you need a complete comparison (a true diff of diffs, or an [interdiff](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/git/interdiff)), see Gautheir's answer or the linked page. If you think the two patches might be *patch-equivalent*, though, and just want to find out, see `git cherry` and its low level plumbing variant, `git patch-id`.

Answer (score 5):

You can skip the temporary files with [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```
diff <(git show ad7cf) <(git show 4ec2d3)
```

It's probably not as simple as you'd wish, but simpler.